# Program to scan 3 files and output the line that's the same in each. Something wrong with the output

Tags: java

So I have the 3 files, and basically everything works in my program so far. My first method reads a line from txt 1 then sends it to method 2. Method 2 reads a line from txt 2, then checks to see if the first line matches the line from text 2. And so forth and so forth. The problem I have with the program as it stands is, in my final method, it prints out the line that is the same in the first 2 methods and the final method. However, it won't stop printing. I have a break if the condition is met but it just won't stop unless I terminate the program. Does anyone know how to stop it? Thanks.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainHub {
    static String line1;
    static String line2;
    static String line3;
    static String creditcode;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{


        firstStore();




    }

public static void firstStore() throws IOException{

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("creditCards1.txt"));

    line1=in.readLine();


    while(line1 !=null){

        line1=in.readLine();


        secondStore(line1);

    }

        in.close();
    }


public static void secondStore(String line1) throws IOException{
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("creditCards2.txt"));

line2 = in.readLine();

    while(line2 != null){

        line2 = in.readLine();

        while(line1.equals(line2)){
        thirdStore(line1);

        }
        }

        in.close();
    }

public static void thirdStore(String line1) throws IOException{
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("creditCards3.txt"));

    line3 = in.readLine();

    while(line3 != null){
        line3 = in.readLine();
        if(line1.equals(line3)){
        System.out.println(line3);
        in.close();
        return;

        }

        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: So I have 3 different methods, each method reads a line from a different txt file. Each txt file contains 100 credit card numbers. I am trying to find the credit card number that is in all 3 text files.

Comment: However, I finally got the correct answer, and found the code, but I cannot get it to stop printing this said code onto the screen, I've tried breaking the while loop but it doesn't seem to want to.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add to a total in line1,line2,line3 so you should make those double(incase of fractional number) and use a Scanner object class to read the file and use its nextDouble() to get the value of the current line and add it to line1; do that until end of file.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: I'm not actually trying to add to the lines though. Basically I want line1(after it has taken the first value from the first line in the first method) and then compare itself to all (values and lines) from method 2, and see if they match with any values.

IF that makes sense?

Comment: make method 1 call method 2 with the parameter of current line value(line1) and then do the comparaison in method 2 while looping though whole file:

Comment: Okay, So I figured most of it out. The only problem I have now is once I print to the screen what the credit number is, it doesn't stop printing the number until I terminate the program. I've even tried a break; after it prints the line but it just won't.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following while loop in the method `secondStore()` to an if statement.

```
while(line1.equals(line2)){
        thirdStore(line1);
}
```

The above while loop will loop forever if entered since you are not changing the value of line1 or line2.

Comment: You sir, are a life saver. Everything now works. Thank you so much.